# Drag-and-Drop from a non emf tree to emf tree

Tags: java, emf, eclipse-emf

i need to drag-and-drop data from a non emf tree to an emf tree. They are in different views.

The nodes of the non emf tree have another data structure than the emf tree.

I want to convert the data in the non emf tree while draging it, to an object which fits into the emf tree.

I need to wrap the object into an ItemWrapper, but i have no idea how to.

I tried so much things but cannot figure out how to continue.

Thank you

Comment: How do you expect us to help you continue if we have no idea of what you've done so far ?

Comment: I created the view, the tree and the data structure of the non emf view. Everything i've tried failed. I am searching for a way how to drag-and-drop objects which have to be converted to emf tree objects. I am not able to show code.

Answer (score 0):

The question sounds too generic. Typically, "EMF tree" contains the contents of EMF Resource (a tree of EObjects). The drag from "non emf" to "emf" should add something to the EMF Model instance as a result.

So, first you need to implement the "transformation" from your "non emf" to "emf" object. 
And then you need to modify the content of your EMF model with *org.eclipse.emf.edit.command.AddCommand* as a result of "drop"

If you will use the proper *org.eclipse.emf.common.command.CommandStack* to execute your command(s) the EMF Edit UI should take care about the viewer update

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For me its not possible to transform my non emf into an emf object. The object nodes are Wrapped in multiple wrappers and after a week trying to transform my non emf object into EObjects and Wrap them i gave up. The wrappers have all protected constuctors. I also found other classes with Wrap functions but they are also protected and expect in their constructors bunch of information i cant provide. All the time i was searching for a simple "wrap"-function and "add to emf tree"-function in combination with drag-and-drop but couldnt find one.